# How can we help souls that died unnaturally in hinduism?

Tags: puranas, rituals, sin, death, suicide

I know of some people who died by suicide and snake bite. I am not related to them. Is there any way as per vedic rituals I can help their souls/atone their sins to reach better state than what they would have got now being committed/attained such bad deaths? Asking out of some kindness and a way to return happiness they shared for others thru their work during their lifetimes.

Comment: During Pitru Tarpana or Shraddha we offer water for those souls too who have died unnatural deaths.